# output gibberish unicode text properly from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

In my mysql database field the unicode text are like this

```
à¤•à¤¾à¤ à¤®à¤¾à¤¡à¥Œà¤, à¥¨à¥ª à¤®à¤¾à¤˜ / à¤¸à¤‚à¤µà¤¿à¤§à¤¾à¤¨à¤¸à¤­à¤¾ à¤¸à¤¦à¤¸à¥à¤¯à¤•à¥‹ à¤°à¤¿à¤•à¥à¤¤ à¥¬ à¤¸à¤¿à¤Ÿà¤•à¤¾ à¤²à¤¾à¤—à¤¿ à¤†à¤—à¤¾à¤®à¥€ à¤šà¥ˆà¤¤ à¥¨à¥® à¤—à¤¤à¥‡ à¤¹à¥à¤¨à¥‡
```

But when the above text is outputted in browser it is properly formatted unicode chatracters in my old website. I have written new php 5.3 website and echo the avove text , i get exactly same as above which is unreadable to visitors. I also have header as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` still no luck.

I am wondering how the above text has rendered correctly on old site and not in new site ? I don't see any special function used in old site either. I am sure someone can help me out on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a utf8_* character set for your table.

or by column

```
col1 VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```